# Gmaps dragging lag

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made an gmaps based travel service, but now have a problem of dragging the map on the desktop devices - it is slow and laggy, but on the mobile devices - dragging through the map is fast - can`t get where the problem is...
The service:
[DoYour.Travel](http://doyour.travel/?nolanding=1)

Why dragging the map si slow and laggy?

Comment: try to record your client side script in developer console, there are really much remove timer/add timer

Comment: thanks! you`ve pointed me to custom jquey scroll bar through this! It`s slowing all the draggind events!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in

> malihu jquery custom scrollbar plugin

it was firing events on mouse button down